# CNN: Unstable of model score vs iteration

Tags: iteration, conv-neural-network, mnist, dl4j

I got my model score vs iteration graph is unstable. How can I improve it?

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8kjU.png)

Here is my code

[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZy58.jpg)

[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MY7k.jpg)

[Code 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSuY4.jpg)

[Code 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga3aF.jpg)

[Code 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GCV0.jpg)

Comment: In the future, please use github gist or pastebin. Screenshots are not suitable at all for reproducing your problem or having other people help you. I'll answer separately. I just wanted to note your question was very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your network looks fairly stock/copy and pasted. I'm pretty sure I've seen this code before.

Without knowing much about your input data I'm not sure if you're solving a classification problem or not but try first switching it to softmax and negative log likelihood on the output.

The output activation and loss function are mainly for binary classification.

You can also get rid of the ReNormalizeL2PerLayer. That might hinder the network from learning depending on your data.

It's also hard to help without knowing much about your input data but sometimes unit mean zero variance may not be suitable for your data set. Consider switching to a zero to 1 scaling instead.

Lastly, for quick iteration times consider overfitting on a small amount of data first when testing. That will help you see if there's any signal in your data and if your network can learn.